# How to save a richtextbox data to a textfile without using the dialog?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a program which will document how my day has been (very similar to a diary). I have managed to pretty much get the program to do everything i want at this stage apart from one thing. This is to automatically save the richtextbox data to a .txt file with the date and time of creation. I can get it save the file but it saves it in The folder TomJ as Record My Life files.txt if the folder "Record My Life files" hasn't been created, What i would like is for it to be saved in the folder Record My Life files as (date + time).txt.

To sum up my question: How do i edit my code to automatically save the reviewtxtbox in the Folder Record My Life files, with the name date + time?

I am a novice, i've only spent about 6 hours using C# but i've done some other programming stuff before, so i would be greeatful if you could explain your answers simply. :) 
Thanks
The code i need to edit is as follows:

```
//creat directory for folders
if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files")) 
{
}
else
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files");
    MessageBox.Show("Directory Created for Diary Entries");
}

private void savebutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string date = datepckr.Text;
        string time = timetxtbox.Text;
        savefile.FileName = date + time;
        savefile.DefaultExt = "*.txt*";
        savefile.Filter = "TEXT Files|*.txt";
        reviewtxtbox.SaveFile(@"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files\", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        MessageBox.Show("Your day has been saved!");
    }
    catch(Exception etc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error Ocurred: " + etc.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the File class within System.IO namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

In particular, you might find File.AppendAllText or File.CreateText useful.

Both take a full file path and file contents as arguments and assuming your program has write permissions on your folder the file will either be appended to, created or replace based on the function call you use.

An example would be:

```
string folder = @"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files\" 
string fileName = "testFile.txt";  

File.AppendAllText(folder + fileName, "test text to write to the file");
```

Comment: I tried this and i think this is the method i will use, i've managed to get the program to save the file in the correct directory but i'm still stuggling with the name, so far it creates the file but it's called "temp", i was wondering if i could rename this file onc it's created? Is there a line of code i could use to change the name?

Comment: If you are using something like my example, the file should be created with the name you specify in the file name variable.  In my example, the file should have been created with the name 'testFile.txt'.

Comment: Thank you :) will this still work if the fileName is a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, fileName is already a variable.  The line `string fileName = "testFile.txt";` is where you specify the name of the file.

Comment: Did you manage to get this sorted? If so you could mark this as the answer?

Comment: No i still can't get this to work :/, I apologise if i'm saying the wrong things, I've set 'string filename = date + time;' but when i save the file it say's the "Given path's format is not supported". Any ideas? I think it's because it doesn't notice the string filename as part of the directory.

Comment: I got it fixed, the problem i was having was that the string filename contained a colon which isn't allowed in a filepath, but now that i'm saving it as just the date it works fine. But yes this would be the answer, sorry i didn't realise sooner.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. An easy way to use a date as a file name would be: `fileName = DateTime.Now().ToString("ddMMyyy_hhmmss") + ".txt";` The format string supplied in `ToString` defines how the date and time will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.WriteAllText(path, contents)`. Something like that should work:

```
//creat directory for folders
if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files")) 
{
}
else
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files");
   MessageBox.Show("Directory Created for Diary Entries");
}

private void savebutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string content = new TextRange(reviewtxtbox.Document.ContentStart, reviewtxtbox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    string date = datepckr.Text;
    string time = timetxtbox.Text;
    string path = @"C:\Users\TomJ\Record My Life files\" + date + time + ".txt";
    File.WriteAllLines(path,content);
    MessageBox.Show("Your day has been saved!");
  }
  catch(Exception etc)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("An error Ocurred: " + etc.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: But beware: [`File.WriteAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx): _"Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten"_.